# difference between string representation and value in perl

Tags: perl, encoding

I am puzzled at the following difference.

```
$str="\xd6\xd0";
decode("GBK",$str);
```

vs.

```
$str="d6d0";
@list=map "\\x".$_,unpack("(a2)*", $str);
$str=join "", @list;
decode("GBK",$str);
```

Why in the first case, it worked to print out the character, while in the second case, it is not working? How can I make it to work in the latter case?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please post a working example. The code snippet you posted will not run on its own.

Comment: @sleske: where is the error? On my side, the code is fine. thanks.

Comment: He means that if you paste that code into a file and run it, you'll get an error about `decode` not being defined, because you didn`t `use Encode`.

Comment: @cjm: Thanks, someone who understands me :-).

Comment: Also, the problem is that there is more than one `decode` function in the Perl libraries. There is at least `utf8::decode` and `Encode::decode()`. Well, it's answered now so it's a moot point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to turn `"d6d0"` into `"\xd6\xd0"`, you want [`pack 'H*'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
my $str = "d6d0";
$str = pack('H*', $str);
decode("GBK",$str);
```

[`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) does not interpret escape sequences, it just concatenates strings.

Comment: +1. right, just figured it out. I spent a lot of time yesterday without luck yesterday. :)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the parser interprets the escape sequences and builds a string that is two bytes long. In the second case, you are creating a string that is eight characters:
`\xd6\xd0`. You probably want to unpack like you are doing, but without prepending the `\x`, and then use `pack` with template `(H2)*` instead of join to put it all together.

Comment: You can transform a hex string into the corresponding bytes with a single call to `pack 'H*'`.  There's no need to `unpack` first.

Comment: @cjm, can `unpack` be used to convert "\\xd6\\xd0" to "\xd6\xd0" if I insist on obtaining the 8-char string first? :-)

Comment: @cjm - Absolutely right. I evidently had blinders on. @Qiang you can use the `x` template to skip characters.